# Connecting Azure AD to an AD (non-adfs)

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I would like to ask if it is possible connecting an Azure AD to an AD which is not an AD FS type? I have read some documentations regarding connecting Azure AD to an on-premise type of AD but AD FS is needed for it. Or is it possible to have an Azure AD connected to an AD DS? Or would it be better to use AD AAD Connect pass-through-authentication?

Or.....

Would it be better to use Azure Logic Apps?

Edit1: Seems like ADFS is optional.

Thanks!

Comment: You are right, we can use Azure AD connect to connect on-prem DC and Azure AD, ADFS is optional. More information about Azure AD connect, please refer to this link.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnect

Comment: @JasonYe-MSFT How about if I have a separate on prem (non-ad users) and on prem AD users? How would I do this using Azure AD Connect?
Correct me if I am wrong, should I sync Azure AD to my on prem AD and have an openid for Azure AD 1-1 to my non-ad on prem db? If this is the way, how should I do this in a proper way, I am confused on how would I integrate Azure AD to a non-AD on prem. Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you want to sync local account(non-ad users) to Azure AD?

Comment: @JasonYe-MSFT No, I just want azure as the middle-ware for users to authenticate to non-AD on prem.  
  
But what I think of is, I would first, authenticate user to AD if response is invalid, the user will go to the non-ad users using API, would this be the right way?

Comment: @ Rex Hope As far as I know, we can't use Azure AD in this way.

Comment: @JasonYe-MSFT So, this type of authentication is only possible by using custom sts? or whatever custom auth it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I just want azure as the middle-ware for users to authenticate to
>   non-AD on prem.

As far as I know, for now, we **can't** use Azure AD in this way.
By default, authenticate user to AD if response is invalid, Azure AD will not redirect it to other page.
Azure AD connect can't sync non-AD users to Azure AD.

Comment: Well, it is about Azure as a whole, I've seen hybrid connections but I think it's a no no as it would give additional complex to the backbone.  
  
The only solution I could think of is, getting a response to my AD and based on that response, it would either continue or I would provide an API as a based authentication for non-ad users and is Azure capable of this? Would this be the 'only' way to do it? Thanks!

Comment: @RexHope Based on my knowledge, if we want to use non-ad, maybe we should use ADFS, but ADFS can't communicate with Azure AD.